# Auto incrementing invoice numbers (getting Integrity constraint violation errors)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an SQL table "invoices", with a unique INT column "number". This is because I need to send financial invoice data to a bookkeeping API, and the number needs to be pre-generated already and incremental.

However I can not AUTO INCREMENT the column because I don't want to screw with the ID being standard AUTO INCREMENTAL.

I tried the following code in Laravel (simplified, in reality a lot more data is added to the entry):

```
$saved = false;

while ( !$saved ) {
            $invoice = new Invoice();
            $number = self::max('number') + 1;

            if ( !Invoice::where('number', $number)->exists() ) {
                $invoice->number = $number;
                $saved = $invoice->save();
            }   
}
```

This code worked, until recently I started getting integrity constraint violations. I figure it's because I can not avoid the possibility that 2 invoices are generated at exactly the same time. Somehow, the system tries to insert records with duplicate numbers.

Is there a better, more watertight way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: One of the solution could be queuing your request data and then processing the request. This way, you can avoid invoice generation at same point.

Comment: This solution is good and possible, but it would prevent the created entry being immediately available for other purposes in the code that follows. Is there a solution that allows me to have the best of both worlds if I need the created entry immediately returned?

Comment: Another alternatives could be wrapping your code in a try catch block and catching the integrity constraint violations error and retrying the try block again. But might not be the feasible solution i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$saved = false;

while ( !$saved ) {
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $number = self::max('number') + 1;
    $check_num = Invoice::where('number', $number)->first();
    if ( !Invoice::where('number', $number)->exists() ) {
        $invoice->number = $number;
        $saved = $invoice->save();
    }elseif ($check_num['number'] == $number) {
        $invoice->number = $number + 1;
        $saved = $invoice->save();
    }
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I don't understand how this code would prevent constraint errors. Once we get those errors, we are already at the point of the save() action trying to execute, right? (resulting in the SQL error) So I don't think that the elseif block is ever reached, in the context of this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).